# Abscence of Learning rate and number of iterations in sklearn Linear Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I have found out that neither Linear, nor Lasso, nor Ridge in scikit-learn use learning rate (what we call alpha) or number of iterations.

I want to know how exactly do they implement Linear Regression under the hood without learning rate, considering that it's at the heart of Gradient Descent?

Comment: You make the implicit but clear assumption here that the underlying optimization algorithm for these models is gradient descent. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Not sure. Can you mention which algo is used in sklearn?

Answer (score 0):

These methods work by minimizing an **objective function**, but here's come the difference between a **Linear Regression** and a **Regularized Regression**. On the one hand, Linear Regression fits the optimal coefficients by minimizing the residual sum of squares between the real values and the predicted values, that is, it is minimizing and objective function like **||y - X||^2**, where y is your real value and X the predicted one.
 For more details of the procedure see [Understanding OLS estimation](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-ols-method-for-simple-linear-regression-e0a4e8f692cc).

On the other hand, **Lasso and Ridge Regression** incorporates another term that accounts for this coefficients, for example, in Ridge Regression the function to minimize is
**||y - X||^2 + alpha * ||w||^2**, where alpha is what is normally known as **learning rate** and w represents the fitted coefficients, see this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461738/how-come-regularization-knows-which-coefficients-to-decrease-and-which-coefficie/461760#461760) for more details on how the regularization shrinks the coefficients values.